# How can I use Extract Method on code that has different constants?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

Given I have code like the following:

```java
void foo() {
  String str = "hello";

  a(str, 1);
  b(str, true);

  a(str, 2);
  b(str, false);
}
```

I would like to extract a new method `c` like:

```java
void foo() {
  String str = "hello";

  c(str, 1, true);
  c(str, 2, false);
}
```

However, the automated Extract Method refactoring will only extract one of the `a`/`b` pairs. My guess is that it dislikes the differing constants. I can work around this by extracting a local variable first, then extracting the method, then inlining the previously extracted variable, but I still have to find all the instances by hand. With that amount of work, I might as well just make the full change myself when I am looking at each part.

Is there a trick I am missing to let Eclipse know to search a little harder to extract this type of code?

Comment: I don't understand.  How could Eclipse possibly know that you want to convert your first code snippet into the second?

Comment: I've never found search and replace that daunting to use.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I would hope for a process like (highlight first `a`/`b` pair, refactor > extract method, modify options to specify that `1` and `true` should not be extracted but instead treated as parameters)

Comment: @BrianRoach - That is true, and if that's the right thing, I will use either the Eclipse search/replace, open the file in emacs, or use some command line tool. However, I'm trying to give Eclipse a fair shot and learn some new Eclipse tricks in the process. :-)

Comment: I went ahead and followed the suggestion from @BrianRoach. I used emacs to do the heavy manipulation then jumped back into Eclipse to tidy up and make sure all the Java pieces fit together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to extract your constants into variable that you can put in the top to tell your tool to pass them as arguments to the extracted method.

```
void foo() {
  String str = "hello";
  int constant = 1;
  boolean boolValue = true;
  a(str, constant);
  b(str, boolValue);

  constant = 2;
  boolValue = false;
  a(str, constant);
  b(str, boolValue);
}
```

Doing an extract method should give the following:

```
public void c(String str, int constant, boolean boolVal){
    a(str, constant);
    b(str, boolVal);
}
```

Comment: Right, I can extract the constants into variables, but I would have to find all of the method calls that include the constants by hand. I tried to explain this in my question, but it must not have been very clear. How could I rephrase my question to be clearer?

Comment: @Shepmaster Oh I see. I am afraid you have to do that manually as the tool can not differentiate between a `true` for method `a` and `true` for method `b`

Comment: Yes - it's also worth mentioning that if you perform a Refactor -> Extract Local Variable, it will (if the box is checked) replace all instances of `true` within the specified scope to whatever the variable is.

Comment: @WChargin The PO did not mention this pattern is all over his/her code baseline. My Answer applies to the code mentioned in the question

Comment: @WChargin - Good call. However, if I were to go down that path, I would re-inline the extracted local variable right after extracting the method, since it isn't really my goal. This would mean that it shouldn't matter if more variables are extracted originally.